# Why does go allow slicing from len(slice)?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Why does the following behavior occur:

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(a[0:])
fmt.Println(a[1:])
fmt.Println(a[2:])
fmt.Println(a[3:])// doesn't panic - why??
fmt.Println(a[4:])// panics as expected
```

[Executable example](http://play.golang.org/p/QWn86CrG43)

Comment: I should have been more clear on this. I understand that from the spec this behavior is expected. But from the programmer's perspective, it seems that low < len(a) should be added to the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[3:]` builds an empty slice which, just like an empty array, is a valid and useful object (in all languages, not just in Go).

An empty slice also still points to an underlying array, a position and a capacity and can sometimes be extended:

```
a := []int{1, 2, 3}
emptySlice := a[1:1]
fmt.Println(emptySlice) // []
notEmpty := emptySlice[0:2]
fmt.Println(notEmpty)   // [2 3]
```

On the other end, a slice with a negative length is inconsistent. It means nothing and thus is forbidden.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from the [Spec: Slice Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions):

> For arrays or strings, the indices are *in range* if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are out of range. For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity `cap(a)` rather than the length.

So the specification allows to use indices up to `len(a)` of the underlying *array*, `len(a)` **included** (or `cap(a)` in case of a slice which in this case has the same value). That's why `a[3:]` in your case doesn't panic.

But it will yield an empty slice of course, because:

```
a[low : high]
```

means the result has indices starting at `0` and length equal to `high - low` and since `high` is omitted, it defaults to `len(a)` therefore `len(a) - len(a) = 0`.

And also (according to the spec) using an index `> len(a)` **will be out of range** and therefore cause a runtime panic:

> If the indices are out of range at run time, a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) occurs.

Comment: Isn't more puzzling and how could you explain `a[1:]`? It will return the result which has indices staring at `0` and length equal to `len(a) - 1` in your meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Because having `0` elements (`3-3`) in the slice is perfectly valid. However having `-1` element (`3-4`) is not.

Such behavior is also consistent with other languages. For example, Java:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).subList(0, 3));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).subList(1, 3));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).subList(2, 3));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).subList(3, 3));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).subList(4, 3));
```

Only the last statement fails.